# How to build JSON Request Body?

Tags: android, json, request

I'm trying to build the following JSON Request Body.

It's my first time with JSON and I'm following [this](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_1-1_-_Encode_a_JSON_object) examples, but still struggling.

I've been taking a look to GSON but wanted to manage pure JSON first, and maybe for something so small it's not worth it to add GSON library?

Could you help me with the code?

Thanks.

```
{
   locations:
   [
      {
         latLng:
         {
            lat: 40.900799,
            lng: 8.606102
         }
      },
      {
         latLng:
         {
            lat: 42.900799,
            lng: 9.606102
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

EDIT:

[Here](http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/#matrix) is the Web Service I am trying to consume and [here](http://www.mapquestapi.com/directions/#matrix) a request sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use json objects.
Do something like that.
Don't write json by hand, you could easily do a mistake.

```
public JSON() throws JSONException
{
    JSONArray locArr=new JSONArray();
    locArr.put(createLatLng(40.900799, 8.606102));
    locArr.put(createLatLng(42.900799, 9.606102));
    JSONObject main=new JSONObject();
    main.put("locations", locArr);
    Log.d("JSON",main.toString());      
}


public JSONObject createLatLng(double lat, double lng) throws JSONException
{
    JSONObject latLng=new JSONObject();
    latLng.put("lat",lat);
    latLng.put("lon",lng);
    JSONObject latLngWrap=new JSONObject();
    latLngWrap.put("latLng",latLng);
    return latLngWrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON notation requires the "" around field names. Values should only be wrapped, if they are string.

```
{
 "locations":
   [
      {
         "latLng":
         {
            "lat": 40.900799,
            "lng": 8.606102
         }
      },
      {
         "latLng":
         {
            "lat": 42.900799,
            "lng": 9.606102
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

You can always verify, if you JSON is correct using
http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Thx @Botis, please look at my EDIT that refers to Web service and JSON Request samples. There are no "" around any of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on maciekczwa's answer. JSON (unlike arguably XML) isn't really meant to be looked at with human eyes. It very quickly becomes very hard to see where one object starts and ends and what's wrapping what.  Use his example to create your main JSON object and then fill it with whatever objects you need to. When you're all done you can convert it to string for transport very easily, without having to look at it, and doing it this way means not having to worry about what labels need to be wrapped in what kinds of quotes etc.

And eskalera is 100% correct. JSON requires all fields to be wrapped in quotes (the rules around whether or not they can be single quotes or *MUST be double quotes vary from implementation to implementation, but again, this is only relevant if you're constructing the JSON manually, as you should only do in instances where it's EXTREMELY simple (and even then... probably not).

Comment: Actually, JSON was _designed_ to be easier to read by humans than XML. And it is.

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir, This is obviously a pretty absurd thing to argue.  I happen to love JSON and much prefer it to XML, but whatever the  design intent was, I'd argue that looking at JSON (especially with the white space removed) is just about useless. A forest of open and close brackets, no clear indication of which closed bracked matches which opened one.  At least in xml the nodes have names, so it's easy to see when a given node ends. How can you seriously argue that JSON is easier to read with human eyes?

Comment: Ah, I knew I shouldn't have added the subjective part to the end. I've heard time and time again that XML shouldn't be used where people are supposed to read it. I guess I shouldn't be surprised opinions differ. But, regardless, the point of my comment was the factual bit. That it was designed to be more human-readable than XML, whether or not it succeeded.

Comment: Right, well... that was what I meant about it being an absurd argument (the fact that it's subjective).  I appreciate the factoid. I doubt it really changes anything. I'd argue that neither should really be looked at by humans. Humans should write/read paragraphs.